# ngIf One-line if statements | Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-template, angular-ng-if

i want to change the name displayed on the iteration using *ngIf*, i am trying to do something like this:

```
*ngIf="detail.name=='dieselG_d'? detail.name='Diesel Green':Diesel Red
```

and the console recorded the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong directive here- `*ngIf` is moreso to check if we should display the content at all, not to make an assignment and change a a variable.  It requires a statement that evaluates a true or false, and cannot do assignments.

Something like the following might work better for you, if your goal is to display a certain name, rather than to hide content with certain values.

```
<div> {{ detail.name === 'dieselG_d' ? 'Diesel Green' : 'Diesel Red' }} </div>
```

Comment: what if i need to set more than a condition?

Comment: It depends what you mean by that- you can also call a function that returns a string but sets some conditions.